# what are the approachies i have to ad the item id as the id of the rendered <Tr> inside my WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am working an asp.net MVC web application, and inside my view, i have a webgrid as follow:-

```
@model  T.ViewModels.GridList<T.Models.Resources>
var gridcolumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
gridcolumns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
      {

        CanSort = false,
        Format =
          (item) =>
             {
               var banner = item.Value as T.Models.Resources;
               return Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", banner.Technology.TechnologyType.Name, new { id = banner.TechnologyID },
new AjaxOptions
{
    Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete (" + banner.Technology.Tag.ToString() + ")",
    HttpMethod = "Post",

    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
});
                    }

        });
            var grid = new WebGrid(
                        canPage: true,
                        rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize,
                        canSort: true,
                        ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");

            grid.Bind(Model.Content, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: false);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

            @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },   // id for ajaxUpdateContainerId parameter
            fillEmptyRows: false,
            tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: gridcolumns

            );
```

now the web grid will be generating an HTML table with rows. and as shown on my above sample code, i have an `Ajax.ActionLink` to delete a row, and i am passing the item ID. then inside the  `OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation"` function i will be removing the related row, as follow:-

```
function deletionconfirmation(data)
{
    if (data.IsSuccess == "reload") {
        location.reload();
    }
    if (data.IsSuccess == "True") {
        $('#' + data.id).remove();

        $.fn.jAlert({
            'title': 'Deletion Confirmation',
            'message': data.description   +  ' deleted successfully',
            'theme': 'success',
            'clickAnywhere': false
        });
    }
```

But my problem is how i can add the items ids inside the WebGrid to be the ids of the generated rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` expression inside the `deletionconfirmation` method will give you the anchor tag HTML element user clicked to start the ajax call. You can use the jQuery `closest` method to get the outer TR of that.

```
function deletionconfirmation(data) {

    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");

    //Do your if conditions to check the data property to determine what to do next.

    $tr.fadeOut(400);

}
```